# Adding header to JSON get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

First of all, I apologize for the vague title or any other incorrect terminology. I'm new to working with JSON and multi-layered (multi-dimensional?) formats aren't talked about much in online tutorials.

My question is, using this data:

```
Lot = "ABC"
infoA = "1.0"
infoB = "2.0"
```

I'm trying to return the following JSON format from a GET request using asp.net web api:

```
{
    "ABC" : {
       infoA: "1.0", 
       infoB: "2.0"
    }
}
```

My model is setup as below:

```
public class LotHeader
{
    public string LotID { get; set; }
    public Lot LotInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Lot
{
    public string infoA{ get; set; }
    public string infoB { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller looks like this:
[image]

Currently, I'm getting the following output:

```
{"LotID":"ABC",
    "LotInfo": {"infoA":"1.0","infoB":"2.0"}
}
```

Is it possible to get the desired output? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired output, you can populate a `Dictionary<string, Lot>`:

```
var response = new Dictionary<string, Lot>();
response[lot.LotID] = lot.LotInfo;
return Ok(response);
```